# Recieving "vector subscript out of range" only on visual studio if variable data contains an integer greater than all elements of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

```
  cin >> q;
  while (q--)
  {

    cin >> data;
    //if this value is greater than all the elements of the vector throwing error
    vector<int>::iterator low = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), data); //does the lower bound

    if (v[low - v.begin()] == data)
        cout << "Yes " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << endl;
    else
        cout << "No " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << endl;// while this should be the output
   }
```

if vector v contains 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
and we enter data 9
then its showing error as vector subscript out of range.

Comment: What compiler are you comparing Visual Studio to?  You do know that accessing elements out-of-bounds is undefined behavior, right?  Visual Studio is smart enough (in debug mode) to flag this error, while whatever other compiler you are using is not.  Instead of using `[ ]`, use `at()`, and I bet both compilers will give you an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Do you really need all this code to test if a value is greater than all the elements of a sorted vector?  A simple test of `data > v.back()` does that in constant time. If you need the return value of `std::lower_bound` then the test `low == v.end()` tells you when it's out of range.

Comment: @Blastfurnace  yeah this much was required for a question on hackerrank.

Answer (score 2):

> Receiving “vector subscript out of range” only on visual studio ...

Visual Studio is correct in giving that assertion.

The debug version of the Visual C++ runtime will check the indices of `std::vector`, and will report issues if there is an out-of-bounds access.

The other compiler you're using is not reporting this error to you, since in reality `operator []` for `std::vector` has undefined behavior if accessing an out-of-bounds item.  Thus you are mistaken when you see the output -- your program has an off-by-one bug.

To prove this, here is your code, but it uses `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int>::iterator low = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 9); 
    if (v.at(low - v.begin()) == 9)
        std::cout << "Yes " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "No " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << std::endl;// while this should be the output
}
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/Hs4Ryy)

Note the `std::out_of_range` exception?  You will now get that same error, regardless of the compiler you will use, since `vector::at()` does bounds checking.

---

Now here is your original code:

[Original code](https://ideone.com/gRoLQh)

Note that you get the output, but you are "silently" accessing an out-of-bounds element, thus the behavior of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [`std::lower_bound()` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) on cppreference.com:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` that is *not less* than (i.e. **greater or equal to**) `value`, **or `last` if no such element is found**.

In your call to `lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), data)`, when `v` is `{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8}` and `data` is 9, there is no element in `v` that is `>= data`, so `v.end()` gets returned to `low`. As such, `low - v.begin()` is `v.end() - v.begin()`, which produces an index (8) that is out of bounds of the vector (valid indexes are 0-7). Which Visual Studio then warns you about.

You need to add a check for the condition when `std::lower_bound()` does not find a matching element:

```cpp
auto low = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), data);

if (low == v.end()) // <-- ADD THIS!
{
    cout << "Not found" << endl;
}
else
{
    auto index = low - v.begin();

    if (v[index] == data)
        cout << "Yes " << (index + 1) << endl;
    else
        cout << "No " << (index + 1) << endl;
}
```